# Laravel collection querying

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have written a query to grab a collection of results, i've added a check to say if a record contains this field hide the record with the id of 2.

**Controller method**

```
  $purchasedProducts = $user->products()->where('purchased', 1);
        if ($user->products()->where('includes_bonus', 1)->first()) {
            $purchasedProducts->where('benefits.id', '!=', 2);
        }

        $purchasedProducts->get();
```

**Blade**

in here i wrote out the foreach loop to be displayed within the blade.

```
 @foreach($purchasedProducts as $product)
                <div class="col-xl-6 p-0 p-xl-4 mb-5 mb-xl-0">
                    <form action="{{route('cancel.product', $product->id)}}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
```

**error received**

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

 <form action="<?php echo e(route('cancel.product', $product->id)); ?>" method="POST">
```

Can you see where i am going wrong?

Comment: you never executed the query you were building with `$purchasedProducts`, its still a Builder, not a result

Comment: How would i modify the above do you mind providing an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the results of the query to anything, you are just calling `get()` on the query you are building but are not doing anything with the returned results. Perhaps assign it to a variable:

```
$purchasedProducts = $purchasedProducts->get();
```